# Привязка данных CheckEdit в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Как мне привязать данные к `CheckEdit`, делаю `парсер` из файлов которые находятся в массиве path1

```
string[] path1 = { "Fine.txt", "Debug.txt", "Info.txt" };

    public List<DataText> list;
    public TextViewModel()
    {

        list = ReadTextFile.LoadDateListFromFile(path1);
    }


    #region Properties
    public List<DataText> DataT
    {
        get { return list; }
        set
        {
            list = value;
            OnPropertyChange("DataT");
        }
    }


    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChange("IsChecked");
        }
    }
```

тут подключаю все это и вывожу на экран:

```
      <dxg:GridControl EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding DataT}"
                     x:Name="myGridControl"  
                     Margin="0,0,3,0"  
                     SelectionMode="Row">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Time Data"  FieldName="TimeData" SortMode="Value" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Classa"     FieldName="DataClasa" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Co to jest"  FieldName="Discription" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TimeData" SummaryType="Count"/>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" Alignment="Right"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" 
                           AutoWidth="True" 
                           ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                           UseEvenRowBackground="True" 
                           AllowEditing="False" 
                           NavigationStyle="Row"  />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

    <dxe:TextEdit Margin="2,92,0,0" 
                  x:Name="MyText" 
                  PrintTextWrapping="NoWrap"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"                       
                  TextTrimming="None" Grid.Column="1"
                  Text="{Binding ElementName=myGridControl, Path=SelectedItem.Discription, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <dxe:CheckEdit Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Debug" Width="54" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                   />
```

Вопрос ! 
Как сделать привязку `IsChecked` в `CheckEdit`, она не работает  ?

Comment: Подключение или отключение _файла_ из обработки — задача бизнес-логики. Вероятно, вы хотите спросить либо как вывести переключатель в UI, либо как опросить/привязать состояние этого переключателя. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: я хочу привязать определённый файл к переключателю, тоесть когда нажымаешь на переключатель, включал содержимое определеного файла файла или его отключал
 string[] path1 = { "Fine.txt", "Debug.txt", "Info.txt" }; это три файла соответствено будет три переключателя

Comment: То, что вы говорите — это бизнес-логика вашей программы. Задавайте вопрос в терминах переменных, логику программы вам придётся писать как-нибудь самостоятельно.

Comment: Как привязать состояние checkEdit к файлу  ?

Comment: Ну, через логику программы. Например, определите объект, представляющий собой файл и флаг, нужно ли его включать.